# Ошибка вызова DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, adapter, dialogfragment

При нажатии на `CardView` должен появляться `DialogFragment` но приложение крашиться, в логах пишет следующие

```
 Process: com.example.test, PID: 5661
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at com.example.test.Attraction.AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0(AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer.java:56)
        at com.example.test.Attraction.-$$Lambda$AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer$9MUGLDlFC3haVjC8L-YKfGaDvo8.onClick(lambda)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5692)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
```

Сам `Adapter`

```
public class AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer.AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer> {
    public ArrayList<ItemPackageOffer> mFavList;

    public AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer(ArrayList<ItemPackageOffer> favList) {
        mFavList = favList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_attraction_package_offer, parent, false);
        return new AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer(v);
    }

    public static class AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView card_image_1;
        public TextView Package_offer_title;
        public CardView Card;

        public AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card_image_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_po);
            Package_offer_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tex);
            Card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.att_po);
        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolderPackageOffer holder, int position) {
        ItemPackageOffer currentItem = mFavList.get(position);
        holder.card_image_1.setImageResource(currentItem.get_Package_offer_img());

        holder.Package_offer_title.setText(currentItem.get_Package_offer_title());

        holder.Card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogPO dialogPO = new DialogPO();
            dialogPO.show(((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "item");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("title_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_title());
            bundle.putString("description_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_description());
            bundle.putString("cost_po", currentItem.get_Package_offer_cost());
            dialogPO.setArguments(bundle);
        });
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFavList.size();
    }
}
```

У меня есть похожий `Adapter` но там при вызове все работает то есть проблема не в `DialogFragment` так как при вызове из другого `Fragment` всё работает.

`Fragment` в котором находится `CardView`

```
public class FragmentAtt extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<ItemPackageOffer> mFavList;

    String URL = "http://qqqqqqqqq.mcdir.ru/dbpo.php";
    RecyclerView mRec;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ImageView GET_PO_IMG;
    String GET_PO_TITLE = "title_po";
    String GET_PO_DESCRIPTION = "description_po";
    String GET_PO_COST = "cost_po";
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_attraction, container, false);
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.rec_po);
        mFavList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerViewadapter = new AdapterAttractionsPackageOffer(mFavList);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        mRec.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRec.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
        mRec.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
        JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL2();

        //recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRec);
    }
```

Comment: передавайте в конструктор адаптера контекст того места где лежит список

Comment: v.getContext() взятый у CardView возвращает ContextThemeWrapper, а вы кастуете его к AppCompatActivity. Если для инициализации диалога вам требуется Activity передавайте её извне. Но лучше передавайте готовый listener, который на вход получает нужные параметры из адаптера и инициализирует и открывает диалог.